# Unable to prevent WARN logging when using a `WebClient` to contact a server which is not (yet) up

Tags: rest, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have a test that needs to wait until a server is up and it uses REST calls to the health actuator to check this. However, this means that initially the application is not yet responding to any HTTP requests, because there is no listener on that port yet. With `RestTemplate` this is no problem, as long as I catch the right exceptions, but if I use a `WebClient`, I get log messages from "`reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect`" stating there was a premature closing of the connection BEFORE the response.

Now I'll accept the confusion caused by some piece of code trying to read a response when there wasn't even a valid connection yet, but I appear unable to prevent this behavior. The `WebClient` is constructed as follows:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.newConnection())
                .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpClient
                        .option(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, httpConnectionTimeoutMillis)
                        .doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                                .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(httpReadTimeoutMillis, MILLISECONDS))))
                .doOnRequestError((request, e) -> { logger.warn("onRequestError: We have a request error: {}.", e.getMessage()); })
                .doOnResponseError((response, e) -> { logger.warn("onResponseError: We have a response error: {}.", e.getMessage()); });
        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build();
    }
```

Now if I use this with a `get().retrieve()` or even `get().exchange()`, I immediately see in the logging:

```
11:02:49.138 [reactor-http-epoll-1] WARN  r.n.http.client.HttpClientConnect - [id: 0x97015555, L:/127.0.0.1:38816 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8024] The connection observed an error
reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
11:02:49.139 [reactor-http-epoll-1] WARN  i.a.t.i.a.AbstractClusterNode - onError: We have a request error: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response.
11:02:49.139 [reactor-http-epoll-1] WARN  i.a.t.i.a.AbstractClusterNode - onRequestError: We have a request error: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response.
```

It appears the `onRequestError` and `onResponseError` log messages were created *after* the internal one. I found the text of this "The connection observed an error" in a handler for uncaught exceptions, but appear unable to catch it beforehand. I appear unable to detect the failed connection in any other way, even though I *am* able to let it result in a default value.

Anyone have an idea how to do this correctly and provide some kind of result without seeing this logs? Setting the log filter is kind of "evading the issue"...

Cheers,
Bert Laverman

Comment: my personal opinion, i would do it the other way around, when the server is up, it notifies everyone that it is up so that everyone can start requesting.

Comment: Yes, I have that for a different set, but in this case I am monitoring the application under test, and I rather not make it search for its tester.